# Install json extension for php with pecl

Tags: php, json, pear, pecl

I try to install json extension for php. Using pecl I get the following error:

```
# pecl install json
downloading json-1.2.1.tgz ...
Starting to download json-1.2.1.tgz (-1 bytes)
....done: 3,585 bytes
Could not get contents of package "/tmp/tmpSdh32B/json-1.2.1.tgz". Invalid tgz file.
Download of "pecl/json" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pear/json"
```

I crawl the web for possible solutions, but without success. Thanks in advance for any pointer.

Best, Andrej

Comment: pecl site down, see [official site](http://pecl.php.net) and this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590888/is-there-any-pecl-mirror)

Comment: I noticed that, but I get the package nevertheless. Don't understand.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of PECL installation procedure, but maybe it tries to download the checksum from the site that's currently not available. Thus it can't verify the archive and claims it's invalid (should display a different message though).

Comment: @Andrej: please close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pecl site was down. After the server was up again, it worked.